# Adicionando +1 no resultado Php

Tags: php

tenho um numero exemplo 300 , quero aumentar ele sempre +1 , tipo usuario digitou que precisa de 50 numeros depois dos 300 exemplo : 301,302,303... ate 305.

O que me recomendam fazer ? um array ou for somando +1 ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="txtNumero"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Gerar"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["txtNumero"])){

$numero_informado = $_POST["txtNumero"];
$contador = +1;

$resultado = $numero_informado + $contador;

echo $resultado;
echo '<br>';



}
```

Comment: Olá amigo. Desculpe, mas não entendi a tua dificuldade. Basta que, quando receberes o input do usuário, tu incrementes o valor... Não precisa de for ou array pra isso, pelo que entendi...

Comment: O modo mais direto? Acredito que seja usando o [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range): `range(300, (300 + 50))`.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo a ultilização de um FOR

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="txtNumero"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Gerar"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["txtNumero"])){

 $numero_informado = $_POST["txtNumero"];

 for($i=0;$i<$numero_informado;$i++{
  $resultado = $numero_informado + $i;

  echo $resultado.'<br>';
 }

}
```

Comment: Joao dessa forma fez o calculo porem, esta calculando com valor com que o usuario digitou, correto seria calcular com valor que esta em "Etiqueta final"

VALOR : 300
quantidade usuario informou : 20

RESULTADO : 301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309......320

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei confuso sobre esse 50. é 50 ou 5?
assumindo que independente do valor, esse seja o número de incrementos:

```
<?php

$final = 300;
$quantidade = 50;
$lista = [];

for ($i=$final; $i <= ($final + $quantidade) ; $i++) {
   $lista[] = $i;
}

print_r($lista);

// 300, 301, 302 ... 350;
```

Comment: o que ficaria dentro de   $lista = []; ?

Comment: if(isset($_POST["txtNumero"])){

 $numero_informado = $_POST["txtNumero"];
 $numero_banco = '300' ;

 for($i=$numero_banco; $i<= ($numero_informado + $numero_banco); $i++){
  $resultado = $i;

  echo $resultado.'<br>';

Deu certo dessa forma, porem preciso que ele gera depois do 300, exemplo ja ir para o 301.


NUMERO  : 300
QUANTIDADE : 5
RESULTADO :  301,302,303,304,305.